# I need help. Tomcat doesn't work in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, port

I have installed Tomcat three times. but this error still occurs.

Error message : 'Starting Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost' has encountered a problem. The server cannot be started because one or more of the ports are invalid. Open the server editor and correct the invalid ports.

I have changed ports many times. but it still occurs.

I have installed many edit tools such as Eclips, Atom, Visual Studio Code, Python Idle, Anaconda3, Android Studio, R, R Studio, Kite, and OS: Windows Subsystem for Linux(WSL) Ubuntu.

I need help how to solve it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZRwC.png)

Comment: I solved it! I just downloaded "Tomcat 8.5 64-bit Windows zip version" and moved it into "eclipse-workspace" directory. and then finally tomcat server starts in eclipse.

Comment: Ideally, use a modern framework like Spring Boot or Dropwizard instead of an external container.